# JsonIgnoreProperties not working

Tags: jackson

I have the following simple class:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "thirdField" })
public class Message {

    private TypeA type;
    private String producer;

//Getters and Setters

}
```

in my test class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {
   public void testMethd() {
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, true);
   Class<T> instanceType = Message.class;

   String msgBody = "{\"producer\": \"clientApp\", \"type\": \"aType\", \"thirdField\": []}";
   objectMapper.readValue(msgBody, instanceType);
   }
}
```

All I am trying to do is to convert the above json string into Message class and ignore the 'thirdField'. But I keep getting

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "thirdField" (class Message), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: , "type", "producer"])
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You've mixed different versions of Jackson.
Notice that you import `JsonIgnoreProperties` from `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate` (version 1.x)
while you're using `ObjectMapper` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` (version 2.x).

Comment: Good catch. I changed it to import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
but still get the same exception

Comment: @kk1957 I reproduced your case with the only difference that I imported JsonIgnoreProperties from com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation and it worked - no exceptions, message object was deserialized corectly. Try to checkout https://github.com/LukaszWiktor/json-ignore-properties-test and run Test.main()

Comment: Yeah, looks like there were other things wrong in my set up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking what the hell I was doing wrong following examples at https://github.com/helun/Ektorp while using latest version of jackson lib.

Comment: @MihaPirnat I'm glad that my answer is still helpful after 3 years.

Comment: @LukaszWiktor yeah, their tutorial still has old example and novices like me still fall for it:
Here's an trivial example class:

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.*;

Comment: flawless answer! Saved the day!

Comment: @gaurav It's amazing that my answer is still helpful after over 6 years!

Answer (score 6):

Try using the last Jackson version (2.4):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"id"})
```

Here you can find an example where it's implement using version 2.4:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-hangman-app/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a Solution to this.
Try to add

```
@JsonSerialize(include= JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
```

About your class

```
@JsonSerialize(include= JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
class ResponseModel {
 //your properties here
 @JsonIgnoreProperties("messageList","contactList","sender")
    var contactList= ArrayList<ContactModel>()
}
```

That will solve your issue buddy.

Answer (score -1):

It didn't work for me any of the above answers, i found a workaround that I have reinitialized the object and values (copied the object).