# Wildfly and Jackson @JsonIgnore annotation

Tags: java, maven, jackson

I am fairly new to Wildfly and some parts of Java EE.

I have a rest service using RestEasy running on wildfly. My 'User' entity has an 'AccessToken' entity. Ideally, i'd like to be able to send the User entity as a JSON without it also sending the access token.

I did some research and found I should be able to use @JsonIgnore for exactly this. However, this annotation isn't available - probably a mistake in my POM.

If I understand correctly, Wildfly uses Jackson so the annotations should be 'provided'. I used a "bom" and what I thought was all of the provided parts, but I'm missing something?

Here is my pom.xml which originated from the quickstart through IntelliJ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source
Copyright 2013, Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates, and individual
contributors by the @authors tag. See the copyright.txt in the
distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>WildFly Quickstarts: example</name>
<description>A starter Java EE 7 webapp project for use on JBoss WildFly / WildFly, generated from the jboss-javaee6-webapp archetype</description>


<properties>
    <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following 
        message: -->
    <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
        resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
    <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>

    <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify 
        tested stacks. -->
    <version.jboss.bom>8.0.0.Final</version.jboss.bom>

    <!-- other plugin versions -->
    <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
    <version.surefire.plugin>2.16</version.surefire.plugin>
    <version.war.plugin>2.5</version.war.plugin>

    <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including a Bill
            of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
            of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
            of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools stack (you can
            read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with some extras tools
            for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate
            stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with extras
            from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All 
        of them are provided by JBoss WildFly -->

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
        as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
        in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
    <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
    <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->

    <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA 2.0 metamodel classes for 
        typesafe criteria queries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever constraint 
        annotations are incorrectly used. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
    <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and Transactional(JTA) 
        JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Facebook library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
        <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name 
        given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- The WildFly plugin deploys your war to a local WildFly container -->
        <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->

    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it to run 
            just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
        <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including Arquillian 
            tests that execute in the specified container -->
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

I did try adding:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

This lets me use @JsonIgnore but then it still shows this field in the JSON returned to the client. I think perhaps my wildfly is using an older version of jackson (1.x) rather than 2? (This gives me that impression: [JsonIgnoreProperties not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986995/jsonignoreproperties-not-working))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annotation @JsonIgnore is a part of Jackson annotation jar.
To include it, use following dependency in your pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks - but after adding this, although I can use @JsonIgnore on the field of my entity, it still shows up when returning it. Just to make sure it wasn't interfearing, I also removed Gson from my pom.xml and my use of it.

Comment: Ah,... so after upgrading to Wildfly 9 this works.. I guess as it's using a new version. Now I suppose I need to update my "bom" that i'm using and it'll run nicely. Thank you.

If you can add to your answer that this works with Wildfly 9, but that Wildfly 8 seems to be using an older jackson version which this doesn't work with it may help others.

Thank you!